# Backbone is not defined in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm just starting backbone and am getting this error.
This is my index.html file:

```
        <script type="text/template" id="login-template">
            <div>Aditya</div>
        </script>

        <script src="./js/router/router.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/views/app.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/views/login_view.js"></script>
    </body>
```

Error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined`

Any help ?

Comment: And from where is the error coming, there's a filename and line number that goes with that error? You probably want the routes after backbone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your router.js file may be using backbone object which is not included yet.
So move inclusion of router.js after backbone.js

```
<script src="./js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="./js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js"></script>
<script src="./js/underscore-min.js"></script>

<script src="./js/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/router/router.js"></script>

<script src="./js/views/app.js"></script>
<script src="./js/views/login_view.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="./js/router/router.js"></script>
```

Is this an external js file that contains the backbone routes. If that's the case then it should be placed after the backbone-min.js.